# algorithmic time

Tags: kernel

I would like to measure the number of cycles used in an algorithm, ignoring latencies for cache misses, i/o, interrupts, page faults. Ideally, it would be the cycle count of a perfect system running an application with infinite pre-loaded cache zero latency infinite bandwidth i/o and nothing else running on the system.

I do NOT want to do this by limiting what is running; I want to discount the accounting for what page misses there were, and interrupts, etc.

I cannot instrument the code; I want to run a process and obtain an ideal time for this.  The goal is to obtain highly repeatable results for timing of algorithms on loaded servers close to the O(.) theoretical complexity sense.

I am fine if this involves instrumenting or specializing the kernel; or the core libraries.  Just not the application.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to account for the effects of the servers being "loaded", then why would you ignore all of those things?

Comment: because I want a consistent measure of algorithm performance independent of load.

Comment: Then shouldn't you measure all those things and then factor them out appropriately? Either that or use an emulator, and then ask the emulator how many cycles it took.

Comment: Yes - those seem reasonable, and hard, which is why I am asking for advice.  Basically timing on an idealized VM.

Answer (score 0):

Modern CPUs have performance counter registers that measure various things (it's more complicated than "cycles", though).

`perf` is a tool to use those counters for measurements, see e.g. [here](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) for details.